# Batch processing versus Single row transactions for atomicity

Tags: sql, oracle, perl, dbi, atomic

I have two tables; one to hold records of reports generated, and the other to update a flag that the reports have been generated. This script will be scheduled, and the SQLs have been implemented. However, there are two implementations of the script:

Case 1:

```
- Insert all the records, then
- Update all the flags,
- Commit if all is well
```

Case 2:

```
While (there are records)
- Insert a record,
- Update the flag
- Commit if all is well
```

Which should be preferred and why?

A transaction for Case 1 is for all inserts, then all update. It's all or nothing. I'm to believe this is faster, or not if the connection to the remote database keeps getting interrupted. It requires very little client side processing. But if the inserts fail midway, we'll have to rerun from the top.

A transaction for Case 2 is one insert, update. This requires to keep track of the inserted records, and updating the specific records. I'll have to use placeholders, and while granted the database may cache the SQL, and use the query execution plan repeatedly, I suspect this would be slower than Case 1 because of the additional client side processing. However on an unreliable connection, which we can assume, this looks the better choice.

EDIT 5/11/2015 11:31AM

CASE 1 snippet:

```
my $sql = "INSERT INTO eval_rep_track_dup\@prod \
            select ert.* \
            from eval_rep_track ert \
            inner join \
            (
                    select erd.evaluation_fk, erd.report_type, LTRIM(erd.assign_group_id, '/site/') course_name \
                    from eval_report_dup\@prod erd \
                    inner join eval_report er \
                    on er.id = erd.id \
                    where erd.status='queue' \
                    and er.status='done' \
            ) cat \
            on ert.eval_id = cat.evaluation_fk \
            and ert.report_type = cat.report_type \
            and ert.course_name = cat.course_name";
    my $sth = $dbh->prepare($sql) or die "Error with sql statement : $DBI::errstr\n";
    my $noterror = $sth->execute() or die "Error in sql statement : " . $sth->errstr . "\n";
```

...

```
# update the status from queue to done      
        $sql = "UPDATE eval_report_dup\@prod \
                SET status='done' \
                WHERE id IN \
                ( \
                        select erd.id \
                        from eval_report_dup\@prod erd \
                        inner join eval_report er \
                        on er.id = erd.id \
                        where erd.status='queue' \
                        and er.status='done' \
                )";

        $sth = $dbh->prepare($sql);
        $sth->execute();
```

eval_rep_track_dup has 3 `number`, 8 `varchar2` and a `timestamp` columns
eval_report_dup has 10 `number`, 8 `varchar2` and 3 `timestamp` columns

Comment: IMHO both should be the same speed if you use prepared statements, client processing is negligible. Why don't you simply run some test cases?

Comment: Thanks, @dnoeth. I'll run test cases. I thought to hear suggestions based on sound practice or theory. I'm also using prepared statements.

Comment: 1) You seem to be suggesting that Case 1 uses a single query to insert all the records; is that the case? (Aside: your question would be easier to answer with an example of your data, your database schema, and the queries you use.) 2) You should use placeholders in *every* statement that uses variable values, whether you're running in a loop or not.

Comment: Thanks @This..Not. I updated the original post with a snippet of Case 1. This was my de-facto choice. But thought of the second afterwards. Use of placeholders are unnecessary in Case 1, but would be in 2 based on the implementation procedure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Hi*
Well if it was up to me I would do the latter method. The principle reason would be if the server/program went down in the middle of processing; you could easily restart the job. 
*Good luck
pj*

Comment: Thanks @joe_evans. I thought of this too after implementing Case 1.